# pandas / matplotlib producing empty plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

I am seeing empty plots of a sudden.  I've reduced it to a simple reproducible example, and I have been blocked for a bit.  Any suggestions?

Here's the program repro.py:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : np.random.rand(10), 'two' : np.random.rand(10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.plot(style=['o','rx'])
plt.show()
```

Running it produces no plot window, the program just ends.

Some additional details:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.2

$ pip list
astroid (1.3.4)
ipython (2.3.1)
logilab-common (0.63.2)
matplotlib (1.4.2)
nose (1.3.4)
numpy (1.9.1)
pandas (0.15.2)
pip (1.5.6)
pylint (1.4.1)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
python-dateutil (2.4.0)
pytz (2014.10)
setuptools (5.5.1)
six (1.9.0)

$
```

Additional info added later:

This seems to be related to the version of something. If I run repro.py without activating my virtualenv, it works fine.  To check non-virtualenv versions, I type `pip list | grep -E 'matplotlib|pandas|numpy'`, and I see this:

```
matplotlib (1.3.1)
numpy (1.8.2)
pandas (0.14.1)
```

Comment: It works for me, have Python 2.7.6, matplotlib(1.3.1),numpy(1.8.2), pandas(0.13.1)

Comment: have you created a `matplotlibrc` file? did you specify a non-interactive backend? do you get an image file when you replace `plt.show()` with `plt.savefig('test.png')`?

Comment: The only matplotlibrc is in ./env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc. The only non-comment line is 'backend: agg'.  That file claims to be a sample, and, indeed, changing the backend line does not change behavior.  I do get a correct image with savefig().